# Regular Expression extracting 2 pieces of information

Tags: html, regex

currently i have many html pages which i need to extract 2 pieces of information. The current expression i am using allows me to extract one information, what if i need to extract 2 pieces of data at the same time.

```html
(?s)\A.*(var vpart=".*?";var pn).*\Z replace $1
```

This is the expression i am using, i need to extract another data in the <  title  > tags, can some one help me to amend the above expression?

Comment: It is a bad idea to use regular expressions to extract information from HTML.

Comment: use groups (A)(B)... and so on. Any expression within brackets is called group.

Comment: (?s)\A.(<title>.*?</title>)(var vpart=".*?";var pn)*\Z i tried this but doesnt seem to work

Comment: i know its a bad idea, but i cant find any easy data miner extensions, the simple ones cant extract the info i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use more groups:

```php
(?s)\A.*(var vpart=".*?";var pn).*(var endpart=".*?";var mn).*\Z
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/LhOc2j/1).

**Replace with**: `$1\n$2`

With more groups, add more `\n$X`.

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                           \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                           matching normally) (matching whitespace
                           and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var vpart="              'var vpart="'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ";var pn                 '";var pn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var endpart="            'var endpart="'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ";var mn                 '";var mn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \Z                       before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```